# Написание бота для Телеграм

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, telegram, бот

Пишу бота для телеграм. Дело в том, что после нескольких перезапусков, бот перестаёт получать ключи.

> Вызвано исключение: "Telegram.Bot.Exceptions.ApiRequestException" в
>   mscorlib.dll Bad Request: reply message not found

С чем это может быть связано и как можно обойти это?
АПИ - Telegram.Bot ver 14.5.0